# Not able to send email from linux terminal

Tags: linux, email, smtp, smtpclient

To send mail I followed the link https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/linux/ubuntu-postfix-gmail-smtp/ .

When I enter the command

```
echo "My message" | mail -s subject myemailID@gmail.com
```

then no error displays but I am not getting the mail. I am attaching screenshot of file /etc/postfix/main.cf. [image: main.cf file]

Comment: For a desktop system you likely just want [`ssmtp`](http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2008/10/21/sending-email-from-your-system-with-ssmtp/)

Comment: Thanks. Actually I need to just enable the less secure app option in gmail.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use your own mail server, you need to reconfigure it as an internet mail server. In debian like systems you can make it via shell like this:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

After this you will receive mails but i think you will can find them in spam dir.

But if you need simply to send mails from command line i recommend you to use another one tool - mutt (read this: https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/how-installsetup-mutt-gmail-centos-and-ubuntu/).